# Сортировка лога Atop

Tags: linux

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отсортировать лог ATOP по определенному процессу.
При открытии ATOP и вызове COMMAND-LINE клавишей 'C', например хочу увидеть только процессы soffbin, а не все, как показано на скриншоте ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. «требуется только одно из набора» ­— это точно не сортировка. 2. у программы atop **нет** лога как явления окружающей нас действительности. // в общем, вы наведите, пожалуйста, порядок в своих мыслях и желаниях, а затем и в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 0):

из хелпа к atop:

```
   'P'  - focus on specific program name
```